# Have the page load before images do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, jquery, loading

I run Ruby threads that use PhantomJS, a command-line headless Webkit engine, to turn a number of urls into images. As of now, the page loads only once all of the images have been generated. Instead, I want to load the page and have a loading animation while the images are generated and show them as they are generated without the user having to reload the page. How would I do this? (I assume AJAX is needed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to process them in a separate process.  Once your request is finished, you lose a reference to the Threads that you started, so you can't just contact them again to ask for a progress report.  I guess you could have the Threads write the result to the database once done, but there are better alternatives.

[Resque-status](https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status) is a gem that extends Resque by allowing you to track the status of individual jobs.  You queue the jobs and take their job IDs, then you can use AJAX to call back to the application and query the progress of those jobs.

Comment: how specifically would I use this to find out when a job has been completed? also, I'm a little concerned that using Resque might be too slow, I need the jobs to start right away...

Comment: The jobs will start right away, provided you have enough available workers.  The queue is "always on".  GitHub, for example, uses Resque when you click "Fork" on a project and it shows you the loading page, then redirects to the forked project... or when you download a tarball of somebody's project.  You should read the README from that link.  There's not much I can put in code that's not in the README.  Collect the UUIDs into an Array and pass them along in the URL when you go to the page that will display the images.  The AJAX part is the least trivial bit.

Comment: so it seems like I can use the UUIDs to identify an individual job, and run an `until` loop to execute the AJAX code when the status is `completed`? Does that sound right? By the way am I doing this all in the controller?

Comment: Well, your JavaScript can poll a URL like: `/jobs/1234,5678,9102/status.json`, where those numbers are the UUIDs.  Then in the controller, query those job statuses and return (in JSON) the URLs for any that have finished generating the image. There's a similar example in the README that returns a file path.  There are solutions that remove the need for polling, but that's beyond the scope of this thread (probably).  node.js, for example, can hold a persistent connection between the client and server, so you can "push" data to the client.  Start simple though.

Comment: thanks. are you referring to the "Passing back data from the job" section? Why would I need to return the urls in the JSON format? Also I've never done polling before. How would that work?

Comment: When you work with AJAX, you want to use a format that is easily generated and parsed on both sides.  JSON or XML are both valid options.  There's nothing to stop you using an alternative format, but you'll save yourself a lot of headaches if if you just use JSON. Polling is just the process of using a repeating loop (with a small sleep delay) to keep running an AJAX request.  You can send the request, then when the response comes back, if the job is not complete, send another request, and so-on.  I'd suggest using jQuery (and possibly, if you're feeling adventurous, Backbone.js).

Comment: ahh ok. So if I'm getting this right, I want to return the urls in JSON format back to my javascript so I can update the DOM element that corresponds to it? would it be impossible to instead work this into a .js.erb file instead of going back to the .js file?

Comment: Correct.  Sure, you can use a .js.erb.  There are various ways you could do it really.  The main thing is that the JS has the UUIDs in it.

Comment: right, and the JS is passing those UUIDs to the controller in the polling AJAX request. Now my last question is where is the JS getting those UUIDs from? aren't they created in the controller? `job_id = SleepJob.create(:length => 100)`

Comment: You'll need to redirect, putting the UUIDs in the query string.  Otherwise, obviously you can pass variables directly into the controller, with `@variable_name`.

Comment: why would I need to redirect in this case? also even if I put the UUIDs in the query string, how would I tell the javascript function which url I want? im failing to see how to specifically connect the controller that generates the UUIDs to the ajax polling function that sends it back to the controller

Comment: @d11wtq unless I send the UUIDs inside of an instance variable to a .js.erb file, but could I send an AJAX request to a different controller action from there? I've only ever sent an AJAX request from my application.js file

Comment: This has gone way beyond the scope of your original question, so I'd suggest starting a new thread as it's too awkward to say much in comments (and one-on-one tutoring doesn't happen very quickly!).

Comment: In short, you don't have to connect to the same controller that generated the UUIDs.  If you have the UUID, you can look up the status of the job from any part of your application.

Comment: aha yes it has, I really appreciate all the help

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could preload the images in the background, which would load up the page entirely while the images download.

more info: [link](http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript)